# How to create new typescript file using command line?

Tags: angular, git, typescript

What to do I want to create new file `main.ts`? I'm writing command but it's showing error

```
"bash: code: command not found"
```

[image: image of written commands]

Comment: `code` is the command used to start Visual Studio Code. If you haven't installed it, the command won't exist. But you can use any editor you want to edit a typescript file: it's just text.

Comment: `touch main.ts` will create a TypeScript file, albeit a relatively useless one; it's just a text file.

Comment: you mean to say ".ts" is just a text file?

Comment: JB Nizet, yeah I've the visual studio code and using that but as I'm new so don't have proper knowledge of this.

Comment: one more thing before this while starting visual studio code , I tried the command "Install code command in path" but did found in visual studio code's command console. So I moved on to next step and now please guide me ,

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried touch main.ts command but it created movie file in windows 10.

Comment: I doubt it, probably just an incorrect file association.

Comment: @jonrsharpe want to know that the code command in my Visual Studio Code isn't working too. I mean when I open command console by pressing "shift+ctrl+p" and type code then the "install "code" command in path  " isn't working .  

And any command starting with code isn't working too.

Comment: And thank you @jonrsharpe the touch command works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular, Git, *or* TypeScript itself; it's because your preferred IDE, Visual Studio Code, is simply not available or not installed. (Since I don't use that I cannot tell you how to install it or make it available but *all* of your question's tags are inappropriate here.)

Comment: Thank you so much @torek but these tags aren't inappropriate. And I already have VS code.

Answer (score 0):

Launching from the Command Line
You can also run VS Code from the terminal by typing `code` after adding it to the path:

- Launch VS Code.
- Open the Command Palette (`⇧⌘P`) and type 'shell command' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.
  macOS shell commands
  [image: how to install to command line]
- Restart the terminal for the new `$PATH` value to take effect. You'll be able to type `code .` in any folder to start editing files in that folder.

Answer can be referenced from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thank you so much @Vivek but the issue I'm facing is that there isn't any shell command in my VS code, That's why I'm asking what to do now ?I tried alot to find out but couldn't as there isn't any shell command

Answer (score -1):

if you use bash for creating new files use `touch <filename>` command